# Trying To Optimise Nested Loops

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I have written some code which calculates the difference between each pair of elements in an array and counts how often the differences occur in the array.

I am trying to move from complexity O(n^3) to O(n^2), can someone help ?

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let n;
let a = [];

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (!n) {
        n = parseInt(line);
    } else {
        a = line.split(' ').map(x => parseInt(x));
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    if (Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]) === a[k] && i < j) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(count);
        rl.close();
    }
});
```

i am expecting
from the input:

```
5
3 1 4 2 1
```

an output of :

```
13
```

```js
const n = 5;

const a = [3, 1, 4, 2, 1];
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      if (Math.abs(a[i] - a[j]) === a[k] && i < j) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Comment: (1) What is your code supposed to do? (2) Reduction in time complexity very often requires a move from brute-force to more intelligent algorithm. What have you researched so far?

Comment: You can easily remove the inner loop. Count the numbers. Use two nested loops to calculate the difference for each pair and increment using the counts. You can replace the inner loop with `count += counts[Math.abs(a[i] - a[j])]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove the inner loop. Count the numbers. Use two nested loops to calculate the difference for each pair and increment using the counts. You can replace the inner loop with `count += counts[Math.abs(a[i] - a[j])]`.

```js
const n = 5;

const a = [3, 1, 4, 2, 1];
let count = 0;
const counts = a.reduce((acc, el) => (acc[el] = (acc[el] ?? 0) + 1, acc), []);
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    count += counts[Math.abs(a[i] - a[j])] ?? 0;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

The whole code:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let n;
let a = [];

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (!n) {
        n = parseInt(line);
    } else {
        a = line.split(' ').map(x => parseInt(x));
        let count = 0;
        const counts = a.reduce((acc, el) => (acc[el] = (acc[el] ?? 0) + 1, acc), []);
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                count += counts[Math.abs(a[i] - a[j])] ?? 0;
            }
        }
        console.log(count);
        rl.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you sir, but if you test your code for the test above it returns 9 instead of 13.

Comment: @YassineRahmani No, when I press "Run code snippet", I get `13`. https://imgur.com/a/HZQ7AL8 Can you post a link to the assignment? I'd like to test my code.

Comment: it is on codeforces

Comment: Can you post a link?